# tkinter treeview - drag and drop?

Tags: python, tkinter

I can see how to cut and paste nodes in a tree or move them up and down using buttons or key bindings.  Is there a way to implement dragging and dropping nodes around the treeview?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to set this up yourself, but it's definitely possible. You'll simply need to make appropriate bindings for `<ButtonPress-1>` (identify the item to be dragged), `<ButtonRelease-1>` (implement the drop), and `<B1-Motion>` (provide feedback during the drag)

Answer (score 11):

Here's some working sample code that handles left-click and shift-left-click:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

def bDown_Shift(event):
    tv = event.widget
    select = [tv.index(s) for s in tv.selection()]
    select.append(tv.index(tv.identify_row(event.y)))
    select.sort()
    for i in range(select[0],select[-1]+1,1):
        tv.selection_add(tv.get_children()[i])

def bDown(event):
    tv = event.widget
    if tv.identify_row(event.y) not in tv.selection():
        tv.selection_set(tv.identify_row(event.y))    

def bUp(event):
    tv = event.widget
    if tv.identify_row(event.y) in tv.selection():
        tv.selection_set(tv.identify_row(event.y))    

def bUp_Shift(event):
    pass

def bMove(event):
    tv = event.widget
    moveto = tv.index(tv.identify_row(event.y))    
    for s in tv.selection():
        tv.move(s, '', moveto)

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=("col1","col2"), 
                    displaycolumns="col2", 
                    selectmode='none')

# insert some items into the tree
for i in range(10):
    tree.insert('', 'end',iid='line%i' % i, text='line:%s' % i, values=('', i))

tree.grid()
tree.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",bDown)
tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",bUp, add='+')
tree.bind("<B1-Motion>",bMove, add='+')
tree.bind("<Shift-ButtonPress-1>",bDown_Shift, add='+')
tree.bind("<Shift-ButtonRelease-1>",bUp_Shift, add='+')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `bUp`? I've removed that and it seems to work in the same way. EDIT: I've removed everything except for bMove and it still seems to work.

Comment: In Python 3, the things to import are `tkinter` and `tkinter.ttk`

Comment: This answer also allows selecting several consecutive items with Shift+Click and dragging them together, but the order among those items changes chaotically all the time while dragging. Also, selecting several non-consecutive items with Ctrl+Click is not possible. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

Could not leave comment on solution so added my 50c here:
to resolve the issue dragging via multilevel tree up and down, you need to specify the parent ID when moving, as per line below:

tv.move(s, tv.identify_row(event.y), moveto)

this might be usefull for someone...

Comment: You will be able to comment once you reach 50 points.  This is designed to keep trolls off the site, and ensure new users follow the Answer guidelines.   Your answer looks OK.